# Starting Rails with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After running Rails for a couple months without issues, I got now this ERROR when starting server (rails s) on MacBook Pro OSX 10.9.
New projects from scratch return same ERROR.
Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !!

```
MacBook-Pro-de-MyName:blog MyName$ rails s
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on [...]
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (-.-.-.-). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2014-08-17 21:22:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2014-08-17 21:22:30] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
Exiting
    /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/utils.rb:76:in
    `create_listeners': undefined method `tcp_server_sockets' for Socket:Class    
    (NoMethodError) from
    /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:132:in `listen'

[etc.]
```